# Confirm registration via email with expressJS

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I already have a setup in expresJS where a user fills up a form, then it goes to a signup route that goes through these steps:

1. Validate data (sanitize email and username)
2. Register      (save the user to the database if data is valid)
3. Login         (using passportJS)

code for that route:

```
router.post('/register',
  userController.validateRegister,
  userController.register,
  authController.login
);
```

The things is, i dont want to directly register the user.
I want to send them an email and then when clicking on the link it actually registers them.

I'm guessing the way to do this is to not use step 2 in my signup route(register), but send the user an email with the link to complete registration, then when the user clicks on the link I register and log them in.

So I thought that if I remove the register method I could skip to the login method, solving the problem of login in the user without registering it(without 
 saving it to the db)

But when I submit the form, I get the error:

`Failed Login!`

Which comes fromt the login method:

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
  successRedirect: '/',
  successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
});
```

So, im a bit lost, on how to change my current setup, where I register them on the spot, to one where they have to click the email i would send them.

This are the methods im using in the register route:

```
exports.validateRegister = (req, res, next) => {
  req.sanitizeBody('name');
  req.checkBody('name', 'You must supply a name!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'That Email is not valid!').isEmail();
  req.sanitizeBody('email').normalizeEmail({
    gmail_remove_dots: false,
    remove_extension: false,
    gmail_remove_subaddress: false
  });
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password Cannot be Blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Confirmed Password cannot be blank!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password-confirm', 'Oops! Your passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
    res.render('register', { title: 'Register', body: req.body, flashes: req.flash() });
    return; // stop the fn from running
  }
  next(); // there were no errors!
};

exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    name: req.body.name,
    location: {
      address: req.body.location.address,
      vicinity: req.body.location.vicinity,
      coordinates: [
        req.body.location.coordinates[0],
        req.body.location.coordinates[1],
      ]
    }
  });
  const register = promisify(User.register, User);
  await register(user, req.body.password);
  next(); // pass to authController.login
};

exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: 'Failed Login!',
  successRedirect: '/',
  successFlash: 'You are now logged in!'
});
```

passport is configured like this:

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why to login a user while he is not registered?**

You can add a boolean property like `isVerified` in your User model setting to `false` by default.
Allow login process only for users with `isVerified` property set to `true`.

When the user clicks the link is included in the registration email, then you set `isVerified` to `true` and user is free to login.
That way, you can run the register method during signup.

When a user submits the register form, there is no reason to login him immediately.
You can render an info page, informing the user that an `account verification` email has been sent to his email acount.

Comment: yeah... ive changed the original question so that there is no need to log the user immediatelly. And your solution sounds very good to me! easier for me also, so how would i do that? I register the user, then I send an email containinga link with  a token and the email? and then when the user clicks on the link it takes him to a route that chnages the flag to positive? is that how you thought about it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, you can  add a User property `verifyToken` where you can assign during registration a random generated value, unique for each user. The link that has been sent to user via email, should contain that token. Then, when the user clicks the link, you can validate the token and verify the user.